# C++ unable cout salary from method

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Entry point is int main() so I try summon pwr.GetSalary to cout outside string "Salary" and double value, however program does not print out anything.
So it is base class.

```
class Employee
{
    public:
        std::string FirstName;
        std::string LastName;
        std::string Patronymic;
        double Salary;
        Employee() {};
        explicit Employee(std::string FirstName, std::string LastName,
            std::string Patronymic, double Salary)
            : FirstName(FirstName), LastName(LastName),
            Patronymic(Patronymic), Salary(Salary) {}
        bool operator==(Employee other) const
        {
            if (this->FirstName == other.FirstName && 
                this->LastName == other.LastName && 
                this->Patronymic == other.Patronymic) 
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
        }
};
```

An daughter class that inherits base class... Here is wonderful method that shall count a salary and print it out...

```
class Papersworker : public Employee
{
    private:
        std::string FirstName;
        std::string LastName;
        std::string Patronymic;
        double Salary;
    public:
        Papersworker() {};
        using Employee::Employee;
        const std::string Job = "Papersworker";
        std::map<std::string, double> Coefficient = 
        {
            {"Director", 4.2},
            {"Papersworker", 1.2},
            {"Guardian", 1.5},
            {"Programmer", 2.5}
        };
        void ChangeCoefficient(std::string Job, double NewCoefficient)
        {
            Coefficient[Job] = NewCoefficient;
        }
        void ChangeNameSalary(std::string FirstName, std::string LastName, std::string Patronymic, double Salary)
        {
            this->FirstName = FirstName;
            this->LastName = LastName;
            this->Patronymic = Patronymic;
            this->Salary = Salary;
        }
        void PrintPapersworker()
        {
            std::cout << "First name\t" << "Lastname\t" << "Patronymic\t" << "Salary\n" << this->FirstName << "\t\t" << this->LastName << "\t" << this->Patronymic << "\t" << this->Salary << "\n" << std::flush;
            for (const auto& i : this->Coefficient)
            {
                std::cout << i.first << " = " << i.second << ";\t" << std::flush;
            }
            std::cout << "\n------------------------------------------------------------\n" << std::flush;
        }
        double GetSalary(double Salary, std::string Job)
        {
            return Salary * this->Coefficient[Job];
        }
};
```

Wonderful int main()'s part.

```
int main()
{
   Papersworker pwr;
   double sr = 0.0;
   std::cout << "\nEnter director's salary\t" << std::flush; std::cin >> sr;
   std::cout << "\nSalary\t" << pwr.GetSalary(sr, "Director");
   return 0;
}
```

If you see a some bad and need optimization don't mind to reply. ._. I do not understand what is going on there in matter of classes building tricks. https://pastebin.com/p7HXaX80
P. S. My homework forces to use private FirstName,LastName,Patronymic,salary...
P. S. S. However, I use Visual Studio 2022 Preview with newest C++ nowadays.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/smrXP.jpg

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: [works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/Tada3T1vh)

Comment: @AlanBirtles I did my best. What can I do to fix problem? The best what I can do is to use pastebin.com to copy paste mine bad code. https://pastebin.com/p7HXaX80

Comment: It's possible that you're on an older version of Visual Studio where you need to set a breakpoint at the end of `main` to avoid having the console window close when the program finishes. That's one of numerous possibilities, though, because I'm not exactly sure what you're observing when you run the program. As with Alan, it prints a salary when I run it.

Comment: I wish I used an old softare but its newest from a box... @chris

Comment: However a problem was switch with enum class... I removed it and changed to if else and all worked. Again that trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> program does not print out anything

Your program(pastebin link you gave) compiles successfully and prints continuously if you change `_getch()` to `getch()` as can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/BdtzZW-t5). But for some reason it goes on forever. Since the link that you gave have around 500 lines of code i didn't take a look as to why the condition is not breaking(or if the program has any undefined behavior). Maybe you can narrow down the problem and edit your question again.

Answer (score 0):

All of the private members of `Papersworker` shadow the public members from `Employee`

```
class Papersworker : public Employee {
 private:
  std::string FirstName;
  std::string LastName;
  std::string Patronymic;
  double Salary;
// ...
};
```

Try this: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ee3Es8hTc) (Untested ’cause I’m in a rush right now, I’ll look at it when I come back)

Also, [be careful](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) with `std::map::operator []`

Comment: Forced to use those field as private... due homework.

Comment: I didn’t have time to fix it properly but I couldn’t leave it like that, so I have [this](https://godbolt.org/z/T93qMqMW7)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not compile as `sr` variable is not defined.
Define `double sr;` before using it in main()'s statement `std::cin >> sr;` and (at least) the program will compile and interact with the user.

```
int main() {
  Papersworker pwr;
  std::cout << "\nEnter director's salary\t" << std::flush;
  double sr; // <- your missed variable
  std::cin >> sr;
  std::cout << "\nSalary\t" << pwr.GetSalary(sr, "Director");
}
```

Program's prints with input 10:

```
Enter director's salary 10

Salary  42
```

Comment: Sadly, I left pastebin.com below. It has it defined.

Comment: @Lith Your snippet from the question is working. Probably you have a problem with IDE. You can try to compile it using a command line.